# opencart 3 save key and value in admin setting

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to save both key and value in the setting table but only the value get stored

here is my code in admin setting.php controller

```
if (isset($this->request->post['config_dual_listbox'])) {
    $data['config_dual_listbox'] = $this->request->post['config_dual_listbox'];
} elseif ($this->config->has('config_dual_listbox')) {
    $data['config_dual_listbox'] = $this->config->get('config_dual_listbox');
} else {
    $data['config_dual_listbox'] = array();
}

$data['dual_listbox_options'] = array();

$data['dual_listbox_options']['option_1'] = array(
    'text'  => 'Option 111',
    'value' => 'Option 1'
);

$data['dual_listbox_options']['option_2'] = array(
    'text'  => 'Option 2222',
    'value' => 'Option 2'
);

$data['dual_listbox_options']['option_3'] = array(
    'text'  => 'Option 3333',
    'value' => 'Option 3'
);

// Save the dual listbox options to the database
if (isset($this->request->post['dual_listbox_options'])) {
    $selected_options = $this->request->post['dual_listbox_options'];
    $options = array();
    foreach ($selected_options as $key => $value) {
        $option = $data['dual_listbox_options'][$key];
        $option['value'] = $value;
        $options[$key] = $option;
    }
       $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('config_dual_listbox', $options);

} elseif (!$this->config->has('config_dual_listbox')) {
    // If no options have been saved previously, save the default options
    $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('config_dual_listbox', $data['dual_listbox_options']);
}


$options = $this->config->get('config_dual_listbox');
print_r($options);
```

and here the code in admin setting.twig

```
<select name="config_dual_listbox[]" id="kt_dual_listbox_3" multiple class="form-control ">
 {% for dual_listbox_options1 in dual_listbox_options %}
            {% if dual_listbox_options1.value in config_dual_listbox %}
    <option value="{{ dual_listbox_options1.value }}" selected="selected">{{ dual_listbox_options1.text }}</option>
            {% else %}
    <option value="{{ dual_listbox_options1.value }}" >{{ dual_listbox_options1.text }}</option>
            {% endif %} 
{% endfor %} 
</select>
```

it only get stored in database like this
["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"]

any idea what I'm missing

I'm trying to reach this result

```
Array
(
    [option_1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 111
            [value] => Option 1
        )

    [option_2] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 2222
            [value] => Option 2
        )

    [option_3] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 3333
            [value] => Option 3
        )

)
```

Comment: "*it only get stored in database like this ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"]*" - So, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: rray
(
    [option_1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 111
            [value] => Option 1
        )

    [option_2] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 2222
            [value] => Option 2
        )

    [option_3] => Array
        (
            [text] => Option 3333
            [value] => Option 3
        )

)

Comment: Please don't tag the question with `twig` as this problem has nothing to do with twig. Did you actually verify `$options`, .e.g `var_dump($options)` *before*  doing `...editSetting('config_dual_listbox', $options);`?

Comment: that is my problem, every thing after this line is not working
// Save the dual listbox options to the database

the code before that is saving only array of values, I need to save both key & value.

Comment: Please do `var_dump($options);` and add the output to the question. You need to make sure that `$options` already has the correct values you want to save and this is the only way to find out.